# How to use Model object returned from spring mvc in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to Spring mvc. I am using ModelAndViewas return object in one of my controllers.
I am not understanding how to access the Model object returned to the jsp for display.
This is my code :

```
   @Controller
   public class GetSongServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/getSong", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSong(@RequestParam(value = "songTitle", required = false) String 
 title) {


    MusicPlayerService service = MusicPlayerServiceImpl2.getInstance();
    try {
        Song song = service.getSong(title);
        System.out.println(song.getSongId());
        // request.setAttribute("song", song);
        /*
         * RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
         * .getRequestDispatcher("viewSong");
         * requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
         */
        return new ModelAndView("viewsong", "song", song);

     }
}



   <input type="text" class="form-control focusedInput" id="title"
                        value=<%="${song.title}"%> name="title" disabled />
 <input type="text" class="form-control focusedInput" id="album"
                        value=<%= "${song.album.albumName}"%> name="album" disabled />
 <input type="text" class="form-control focusedInput" id="artist"
                        value=<%= "${song.artist}"%> name="artist" disabled />.........



 public class Song{
private int songId;
private Album album;
private String title;
private int rating;
private String artist;
private String composer;
private Genre genre;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't access the model through the JSP. `Model` (and all corresponding types: `ModelAndView`, `ModelMap`, etc.) is a Spring abstraction around `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

When Spring has finished invoking your handler method, it will move all model attributes it has collected to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

You can access these in JSP with the EL expression

```
${some.attribute}
```

but don't try to put EL within a scriptlet like you do here

```
<%= "${song.artist}"%>
```

Comment: @kumuda _It did not work._ Is not very useful. Edit your question. Explain what you tried, why, and **how** it did not work. Explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

In order to your JSP page be able to display the property of your object you need to implement a public getter of it.

In your case, your class `Song` has an attribute `title` but as it's a private attribute you gonna need a public method called `getTitle()` returning the `title` attribute. Your JSP will be able to render `title` if you write something like that:

```
<input type="text" value="${song.title}" name="title" disabled />
```